# Mailman mailbox problem using 2d arrays and for loops

Tags: java, arrays

This program is supposed to create a boolean array with 150 "mailboxes". The first `for` loop is supposed to set them all to "closed" defined by false. The second `for` loop should start at the second mailbox, `index[1]` and open every even. The third and fourth `for` loops are supposed to start at the third mailbox `index[2]` and open every third then after reaching the 150th return to the fourth `for` loop and open every third. The final `for` loop is supposed to print out which for loops are closed. I haven't been able to get it to run past line 17.

```
public class CS2LAB1 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    boolean[] mailboxes = new boolean[149];

    /*this function sets all mailbox doors to closed*/
    for(int i = 0; i <= mailboxes.length; i++)
    {
     mailboxes[i] = false;
    }

    /*This function uses a for loop to begin at mailbox 2 and open every even mailbox
    */
    for(int count = 1; count <= mailboxes.length; count = count + 2)
    {
     mailboxes[count] = true;
    }

    /*This function starts at 3 and opens every 3rd mailbox, next it goes to 4 and opens every 3rd mailbox followed by the 4th then 5th then 6th */
    for(int count2 = 2; count2<=mailboxes.length; count2++)
    {
        for(int count3 = count2; count3 <= mailboxes.length; count3 = count3 + count2)
        {
          if(mailboxes[count2] = true)
          { mailboxes[count2] = false;}
          else{ mailboxes[count2] = true;}    
        }
    }

    /*This function outputs all the closed doors*/
    for(int print =0; mailboxes.length>=print; print++)
        if(mailboxes[print] = false)
        {
            System.out.println("Mailbox" + print++ + "is closed" );
        }
}
```

}

Update: I went through and changed the `boolean` values so that closed is now equivalent to `true` and open is for `false` off the basis that any `boolean` array is already set to `false`. I did not get the correct output instead the program outputs all even mailboxes as opened

moreover I believe I've narrowed the problem down to the nested for loop. The `if statements` within are never used and I do not understand why. Any ideas?

```
    for(int count2 = 2; count2<= 149; count2++)
    {
        for(int count3 = 2; count3 <= 149; count3 = count3 + 3)
        {
          if(mailboxes[count3] = false)
          { mailboxes[count3] = true;}
          else{ mailboxes[count3] = false;}    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `for` loop is probably throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundException`. Array's in Java are 0-indexed meaning that they start at `0` and go all the way up until `Array.length - 1`. Therefore in order to traverse an entire array one would iterate from `for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`.

Your `for` loop is traversing from `for(int i = 0; i <= mailboxes.length; i++)`. Meaning the last value for index `i` is `149` when the arrays indexes go from `[0, ..., 148]`.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I think I have the for loop in that syntax but it's still throwing an error at mailboxes[i] = false .

Comment: Thank you, major progress was just made. The program will now run but will display no output. I believe the main culprit is this if statement,     
        if(mailboxes[count2] = true)
              { mailboxes[count2] = false;}
              else{ mailboxes[count2] = true;}